# docker формирование нового image под свои нужды

Tags: docker, docker-compose

на сайте digitalocean нашел пример как можно с помощью yml файла развернуть чреез докер сайт

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8080:80
wordpress_db:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: examplepass
phpmyadmin:
  image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
  links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
  ports:
    - 8181:80
  environment:
    MYSQL_USERNAME: root
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: examplepass
```

я хочу из этого примера вместо wordpress image подставить свой image а остальная сборка чтобы была как в примере.
вопрос таков как правильно "делать" образ если я хочу его сделать со своего образа? напрмер создал на hub.docker.com свою репу - запушил туда репозиторий и хочу его теперь "до ума довести" но изначального файла Dockerfile уже нет чтобы установить дополнительный софт на образ и изменить его чтобы пересобрать заново.

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно поступать в таких случаях. 
PS: собираюсь код подтягивать из git репозитария при сборке, чтобы при необходимости делать правки в git'e, или как лучше поступать?

Comment: "я хочу из этого примера вместо wordpress image подставить свой image"? Так это... берёте... и подставляете. Что мешает-то?

Comment: ну вот допустим я создал репу docker pull igoracrapp/medicalappmrt (там по сути щас ничего не нужно) из етого я хочу сделать то что будет монтироваться. Что не ясно - workflow. Например из гит - все елементарно - стянул репу, сделал правки - добавил\удалил что то далее коммит и запушил. Стесь же тяну теперь ету репу - допустим стягивается "состояние" если мне нужен будет изменить сборку, то как внести изменения в image?

Comment: как можно подредактировать Dockerfile ?

Comment: Скорее всего, вы **не** будете вносить изменения в сам образ. Это возможно, но нетипично. Вносить изменения вы будете скорее в сам `Dockerfile`, в результате его пересборки будет получаться новая версия образа. "Дерево версий" как таковое будет расти не "вверх", как в `git`, а "вбок", как если бы постоянно делался `git commit --amend`, только вместо коммитов состояния образа. У вас сейчас в вопросе свалка из расплывчатых вопросов, сведите к чему-то конкретному, разделите на несколько отдельных точных вопросов, если надо.

Comment: да вы правы, наверно нужно будет пересоздать вопросы в разбивку и конкретно, а то есть непонятные мне моменты и их много и "вычитать" их неполучилось покачто.

Comment: тоесть вы писали в коммите то что на локалке пересобирать образ к нужной конфигурации, а только когда продукт будет готов то выкатывать его в репу на docker hub ?

Comment: Да, примерно. `docker-compose` даже имеет директиву `build`, которая собирает образ из указанной папки, а не берёт его с Хаба. М... кажется, часть вопроса в этом и состояла и я уже начинаю отвечать в комментариях, что нехорошо. **Разделите :)**

Comment: да, спасибо) я отмечу ваши полезные комментарии)) тоесть нужно получается хранить исходники образа, иначе их потом не получить из готовой репы?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37681/discussion-between-d-side-and-igor-kalamurda).